# I tried to install oracle 18c on ubuntu 20.04, how to configure it

Tags: oracle

```bsh
root@akbar:/home/akbar# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure

/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'

Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.

Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:

Confirm the password:

Configuring Oracle Listener.

su: user oracle does not exist

Listener configuration failed. Check log '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log' for more details.

root@akbar:/home/akbar#
```

Comment: What does the log say ? Should you create the oracle user before trying to configure ?

Comment: yes i ve, but thats only clear one error. other error still available

Comment: Oracle software generally does not play well on Debian or SuSE-based distributions. This issue can be resolved, but it will cause massive headaches with every future software installation and update on that machine until you toss it out the nearest airlock. I would *strongly* advise running Oracle in a VM with a RHEL/Fedora OS. This is the easiest — and most versatile — option when putting an Oracle DB on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of time by downloading Oracle's Virtual Box and then grabbing some of their Development VMs to load into it.  They have pre-configured tools, databases, etc. so that you don't have to waste your time doing these things.

https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html#dbapp

It's all free.