# Error: Could not find or load main class oracle.net.ca.NetCA

Tags: java, password, oracle, database

I'm getting this error message, how do I fix it?

[image: Image where I got error Kubuntu 20.04]

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316074/i-tried-to-install-oracle-18c-on-ubuntu-20-04-how-to-configure-it

Comment: Officially, Oracle does not support OracleDB on Ubuntu.  This may be a case where you need to have a VM or container of Oracle Linux for this, as they don't publish truly-supported alternatives for installing OracleDB.  Or a Docker image (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images is apparently available)

Comment: I tried installing it in docker but TNS problem occurs when we boot oracle db 2nd time 
(First time it works)